# SQL server : Split string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have the text in the table in the same row. I need to split it into two columns with date and text. I use t-sql

**Input**

[image]

then  I need two columns

**Output**

```
|6.08.12 | Nor. tel. reserviert bis |
|12.08.12| meldet sich
```

Please help my.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split after the first space.  This is easy enough:

```
select left(notizen, charindex(' ', notizen) - 1) as col1,
       stuff(notizen, 1, charindex(' ', notizen), '') as col2
from t
where notizen like '% %';
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE #T (
  Id int,
  notizen varchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #T (Id, notizen)
  SELECT
    1,
    '6.08.12  Nor. tel. reserviert bis '
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2,
    '12.08.12 meldet sich'

SELECT
  *
FROM #T

SELECT
  Id,
  RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(notizen, 8))) AS Date,
  SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(notizen)), LEN((LEFT(notizen, 8))) + 1, LEN(notizen)) AS notizenue
FROM #T